# Is google charts stringFilter limited at 29 characters?

Tags: javascript, google-visualization

I've implemented a google charts table chart on a dashboard with a string filter. The filter is set on any and works fine. But when I search any Text longer than 30 characters (even if it is in the list itself) it won't return anything.

```
var filterMatText = new google.visualization.ControlWrapper({
            'controlType': 'StringFilter',
            'containerId': 'fullTableFilterMatText',
            'options': {
                'filterColumnLabel': 'Materialkurztext',
                'matchType': 'any',
                'width': '50',
                'height': '100%',
                'ui': {
                    'caption': 'Text suchen',
                    'labelStacking': 'vertical',
                    'label-sepaerator': 'true',
                },
            },

        });
```

Is the filter limited and can I increase this limit? It doesn't say in the documentation. And I am out of ideas.

Edit: It does not seem to be the length of the string, since the answer proved it. The String `1.4404 (316L) RPD HIFLO 15 S 850x380`  does not work, only if I shorten it to `1.4404 (316L) RPD HIFLO 15 S` . What might be wrong with that string?

Comment: there shouldn't be a limit, found an old example, seems to work fine here --> [https://jsfiddle.net/WhiteHat/br2pneum/](https://jsfiddle.net/WhiteHat/br2pneum/)

Comment: I don't know where the error might come from. The string I am searching for is: "1.4404 (316L) RPD HIFLO 15 S 850x380 " and it's copied straaight from the table. But it only finds a result with: "1.4404 (316L) RPD HIFLO 15 S ".

Comment: I checked a 40 character one now and this one works as well. Whatmight be wrong with that string: "1.4404 (316L) RPD HIFLO 15 S 850x380 "?

Comment: I've found the problem. There is a double space in my string, which is not put out on the table. I will accept this answer, since it is on the topic.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As pointed out from WhiteHat there is no limit within 40+ characters. My problem came from having a string with two spaces right next to each other, which got replaced with a single space in the output of the table. But the filter goes through the source, resulting in the filter not matching.